# Optimal strategy for a dice game with an element of choice

Tags: probability, dice, dynamic-programming

This was given as part of an assignment on dynamic programming using Bellman equations, but I feel like it could also be solved purely in terms of probability. (I've already submitted the assignment, just trying to see if the other way I came up with is correct).

Consider the following dice game:

> The object of the game is to be the first player to reach 100 points. Each player’s turn consists of repeatedly rolling a die. After each roll, the player is faced with two choices: roll again, or hold (decline to roll again).
>
> - If the player rolls a 1, the player scores 1, and it becomes the
>     opponent’s turn.
> - If the player rolls a number other than 1, the
>     number is added to the player’s turn total, the sum of the rolls
>     during the turn, and the player’s turn continues.
> - If the player
>     holds, the turn total is added to the player’s score, and it becomes
>     the opponent’s turn.
>
> For example, a couple of turns can go like this:
>
> - Player A’s turn begins. A chooses to roll and rolls a 5. Turn total
>     is 5. Then A decides to roll again and gets a 3. Turn total is 8. A
>     chooses to roll again and gets a 6. With the turn total at 14 now,
>     player A decides to hold. Now the turn total 14 is added to player
>     A’s score, and the game moves to B’s turn.
> - Player B’s turn begins.
>     B chooses to roll and rolls a 4. Then B chooses to roll again and
>     gets a 2. Turn total is 6. Decides to roll again and gets a 5. Turn
>     total is 11. Chooses to roll again and gets 1. Now that B rolled a 1,
>     the turn total is discarded, and simply a ‘1’ is added to player B’s
>     score. The game goes to A’s turn again.

Here is what I have done:

At each roll, we can roll a 1 with probability $\frac{1}{6}$ and our turn end with this score, or roll higher than a 1 with probability $\frac{5}{6}$. In the later case, the expected value if we roll higher than a 1 is $(2+3+4+5+6)/5 = 4$

So we can think of the expected value of rolling $n$ times as this:

[image]

The expected value is thus:

\begin{align*}
E(\text{1 roll}) & = \dfrac{1}{6}(1) + \dfrac{5}{6}(4)\\
E(\text{2 rolls}) & = \dfrac{1}{6}(1) +  \dfrac{1}{6}\dfrac{5}{6}(1) + \left(\dfrac{5}{6}\right)^2(8)\\
E(\text{3 rolls}) & = \dfrac{1}{6}(1) +  \dfrac{1}{6}\dfrac{5}{6}(1) + \dfrac{1}{6}\dfrac{5}{6}\dfrac{5}{6}(1) + \left(\dfrac{5}{6}\right)^3(12)\\
\vdots\\
E(n \text{ rolls}) &= \dfrac{1}{6}\sum_{k = 0}^{n-1}\left( \dfrac{5}{6}\right)^k + \left(\dfrac{5}{6}\right)^n(4n)
\end{align*}

Computing this for different values of n:

[image]

This function reaches a maximum for six rolls, so I concluded that the optimal strategy is to always roll six times. Is this correct reasoning?

Comment: No, it isn't.  The right thing to do in any situation will depend on your score, your opponent's score, and your turn total.   If your opponent has $99$ points, you should probably keep rolling until you either get to $100$ or roll a $1$, as your opponent is certain to win if he gets another turn.  See the discussion of Piglet at https://cupola.gettysburg.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1003&context=csfac

Comment: Thank you for the link to the paper! Didn't realize this game had a name or I would have looked it up.

Comment: Well, the real game is "pig" where you lose the entire turn total if you roll a $1$.  That's harder to analyze, so the authors developed piglet as a first approximation, solved that, and went on to solve pig.  It's an interesting paper, and easy to read.